# Finding the angles in diagram with a circle with many chords

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

So, i'm really bad at these types of problems, but I've been working through a bunch trying to get better. I'm a bit stumped on this one.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGMgt.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTaw5.png]

My thoughts so far:

$60=<BAC$, $y=<BCD$ and $x$ all subtend the arc $\overline{AD}$. But yeah, I'm not exactly sure what to make of angle $x$. It subtends arc $\overline{AD}$ but it's not formed by an angle in the center of the circle or on the circle so i'm a bit baffled..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a big hint: $\angle BAC=\angle BDC=90^{\circ}$ (subtends diameter), $\angle OAB=60^{\circ}$ ($OA=OB$), then $\angle OAC=\angle OCA=30^{\circ}$. Thus, $y=90^{\circ}-26^{\circ}-30^{\circ}=34^{\circ}$. Can you find $x$?

Comment: Thank you so much!! There are so many possibilities for trying to figure out problems like this, ugh! I need more practice..

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ subtend the same arc, can we say that $2x=y$?

Comment: @Frogwilldo: NO! That would be true if vertex of $x$ was also the center of the circle. Even then, it would be the other way around, $x=2y$. Here is a good summary of circle theorems: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT725/ReviewCir/ReviewCir.htm

Comment: Great link! Thank you so much